# How to pass expressions to bench::mark exprs argument

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list containing functions:

```
funcs <- list(
  loop = function(n) {
    result <- 0
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
      result <- result + i
    }
    result
  },
  vect = function(n) sum(seq_len(n))
)
```

If I want to benchmark them using [`bench`](https://bench.r-lib.org/) I can do this:

```
N <- 1e6
bench::mark(funcs$loop(N), funcs$vect(N)) # Ok
```

which works fine. However, I have two minor nits with this approach.

1. I need to remember to write an expression for each function.  For example, if I add a function to `funcs` I need to remember to also add it as an expression to `mark(...)`.
2. I'm also repeating the evaluation of the function (i.e., `(N)` is repeated more than once). Obviously it's trivial here, but it's a form of repetition all the same.

It seems that the `exprs` argument to `mark` should help by allowing me to do something like:

```
bench::mark(exprs = lapply(funcs, \(f) expression(f(1e6)))) # Error in f(1e+06) : could not find function "f"
```

However, it generates an error. How can I generate a list suitable for passing to the `exprs` argument?

Comment: You can use `bquote()` or `substitute()` instead of `expression()`. Either way you’ll need to let the function know to un-quote the function.

Comment: `bquote` results in the same error, while `substitute` results in the error message "Error in eval(e, env) : object 'X' not found".  I suspect I'm not understanding your second sentence (i.e., where you mention unquoting).

Comment: It turns out that `bench::mark(exprs = lapply(funcs, \(f) { g <- f; substitute(g(1e6)) }))` works. So clearly it has something to do with how a variable is captured (I've seen a similar problem in C# when closing over a loop variable). However, I can't say I fully understand the issue. At least it's a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `expression()` one needs to use `subsititute()` (as indicated by Konrad Rudolph). However, as originally written, it captures the wrong parameter; reassigning to a temporary variable fixes this. Thus the following code works.

```
bench::mark(exprs = lapply(funcs, \(f) {
  g <- f
  substitute(g(1e6)) 
}))
```